# Text file in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image: The screenshot of the text file I'm trying to read from]

I have a text file in python jupyter notebook. The questions is asking 'Count the numbers larger than 0.1.' I do not know how to write a code for this. The text file has names and integers. I think I can create two lists for this, but not sure what how to get the output for the numbers larger than .1.

This is the code that I have written so far.

```
def ans9(file):
    infile = open(file)
    contents = infile.read().split()
    infile.close()
```

Comment: Hi Karoline! Can you show us what you've tried so far, as well as part of what the text file looks like? Without more information, it's hard to tell what you need.

Comment: Hey Arya, I have added a photo of the text file in the question I posted. This is what I have so far. def ans10(file):
    infile = open(file)
    contents = infile.read().split()
    infile.close()

Comment: Hello! Please add the "what I have so far" in the question. It is easier to find it and the code will be formatted properly.

Comment: Images of text should be avoided on Stack Overflow, paste the text instead in a block `like this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = []
    for line in f:
        data.append(float(line.split()[1]))


print(len([i for i in data if i > 0.1]))
# prints 2 for the following data:
Smith 0.88
Johnson 0.68
Brown 0.04
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked! You can accept the answer by clicking the right sign.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a count of them, something like this would work:

```
def ans9(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as infile:
        count = 0
        for line in infile:
            if float(line.split('\t')[1]) >  0.1:
                count += 1

    return count
```

If you want a split up representation of the data:

```
def ans9(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as infile:
        items = []
        for line in infile:
            item = line.split('\t')
            if float(item[1]) >  0.1:
                items.append(item)

    return items
```

Would return a list that looks like `[["a", "0.22"], ["b", "0.11"]]` and you could iterate through it fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with [tgikal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4777984/tgikal)'s use of lists-of-lists. The correct data structure in this case is probably a dictionary (yes indentations look funny but PEP-8 compliant and if you ignore them it reads like English) :

```
filename = 'people.txt'
with open(filename) as file:
    filtered_users = {user:score 
                      for user, score in (line.split() 
                                          for line in file
                                          if line)
                      if score > 0.1}

print(len(filtered_users))
```

Comment: The reason I avoided suggesting a dictionary is the possibility of duplicate names, and the problems associated with that, such as overwriting of keys and values. If split-up data is even what is needed, as the first part of my answer and the question indicates, the count is probably all they want.